# Orchard add Sign in as menu item

Tags: orchardcms, menuitem

I am trying add to main menu new item which will be Sign In/Sing out action. Administration page does not give posibility to add conditional Sign In/Sign Out link.
I found one solution where I added to Menu.cshtml another li tag with condition for Sign In/Sing Out. But i think there should be better solution to do this and that is what I am asking for.

Comment: The navigation in 1.5 is completely extensible. Just look at the existing menu item providers. David Hayden has a post on that as well.

Comment: Yeah!, Thank you for the name of David Hayden. I found his post about injecting [Link](http://www.­davidhayden.­me/­blog/­dynamically-­injecting-­menu-­items-­in-­orchard-­cms). This one helps me find soultion.